# Can't create React native project because Installing Bundler failed

Tags: react-native, bundle, gemfile, npx

got an error while creating a react native project

[image: 1]

I have tried several ways on the net but it doesn't work

i tried some ways on net but it doesn't work like bundle install or rvm install 2.7

Answer (score -1):

Just run `bundle install` in you app's root folder